# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, module

I'm trying to build an app with python and I need it to interface with the web. I'm trying to use selenium for this but I keep getting this error.

Here's the code I'm using.

```
# selenium for web driving
import selenium

# SELENIUM & WEBDRIVER
# importing webdriver manager for python. selenium needs this
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.utils import ChromeType

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install()))
```

And the error I'm getting:

```
C:\Users\myname\Miniconda3\python.exe "//this.is.a.netword.drive/ulappa$/myname/Testiympäristö/OAMK kurssi/downloader.py"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\this.is.a.netword.drive\ulappa$\myname\Testiympäristö\OAMK kurssi\downloader.py", line 15, in <module>
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How do I fix this? I've installed selenium and webdriver-manager in cmd.

Answer (score 2):

now in packages webdriver_manager in module ChromeType is in

```
from webdriver_manager.core.os_manager import ChromeType
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the correct python environment? Do you have multiple python instances installed?

Comment: Perhaps not. Infact I'm such a noob that I'm not even sure how python environments work. I have python 3.10.4 installed, but QGIS also bundles some kind of python with itself afaik. Again, I'm kinda in over my head so take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: How are you using Python right now? What IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using pycharm. I also just created a venv in cmd and installed the modules there, after googling about that more. I've yet to figure out how to activate the venv in pycharm though. And if I need to uninstall the modules I've been trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to change the set up import (`from webdriver_manager.core.utils import...`) :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.core.utils import ChromeType
```

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install()))`